# Local Classpath in Classloader disappearing?

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

I have the following code in a class in a WebService:

```
try { 
    master = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle(filename, Locale.getDefault(), classLoader);
} catch (MissingResourceException e) { 
    /*logs error*/ 
    throw new PropertyException(e);
}
```

This works fine the first time it executes.  Later, I have fired a (Java) timer to reinitialize the properties in the application, and call this code a second time.  It then fails, saying it cannot find the file.

I've noticed that the "Local Classpath" that is evidently part of `toString()` for the CompoundClassLoader is a very long string in the first case, and an empty string for the second.  It would make sense that the file cannot be found if there's no classpath, but I don't understand why the "Local Classpath" would have changed.

The Classloader in question gets passed through 4 routines, but it starts life like this:

```
... MyClassName.class.getClassLoader() ...
```

Here's the output of `toString()` on CompoundClassLoader the first time (I got this from the variable value window at the bottom of the "Variables" view in RAD/eclipse):

```
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@1fd7f71f[appwar:myService] 
Local ClassPath: D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\ejbServices\build\classes;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myServiceWeb\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myServiceWeb\WebContent;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\dao;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-pool-1.5.3.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\dataaccess-manager-1.0.0.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\log4j-1.2.15.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\domain\bin;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\local-calendar-1.1.2.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\ourCommon.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\reference-data-1.1.4.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\config-3.2.3.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\utilities-3.0.5.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\componentMediation-5.2.3.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\validator-1.2.0.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\CoreServices.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-chain-1.2.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-collections-3.1.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-digester-2.0.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-validator-1.3.1.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\locale-manager-1.0.7.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-codec.jar;D:\Sandboxes\myServices\myService\myServiceWorkspace\myService\commons-httpclient.jar 
Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@adab1a80 
Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST
```

and the second time:

```
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@1fd7f71f[appwar:issnrcServices] 
Local ClassPath:     
Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@adab1a80    
Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST
```

I would guess that the EJB environment is involved somehow, but I don't know how.  The ID of the object on which I call `.class.getClassLoad()` is the same in both cases, why can't the bundle be found the second time?

Comment: These appear to be distinct class loaders from different WARs.  Is your "MyClassName" included in two WARs?  An empty local classpath can mean that the class loader was disposed when the module/application was stopped.  Are you stopping/restarting or repackaging/redeploying your application?

Comment: @bkail I don't think it can be stopping/restarting/repackaging-or-redeploying.  I set a java.util.Timer to fire only a few minutes after the server starts, and to make the second call.  There's only one WAR, afaik. I take it as indicative that the object ID is the same in both cases; I don't think those can be different objects.  What could clear the classpath from that object?

Comment: The "object id" is just a hashCode.  The class loader might override that (I forget), or the JVM could have reused the identity hash code.  I developed the class loader naming/tagging infrastructure (where "appwar" means policy=APPLICATION for those application names), and at the time I wrote it, the class loader name was only ever set during creation, so if those are actually the same class loader instance, I don't know what's happening.  You could try opening a PMR with IBM.